# How to identify and delete all the images/pdf's which are not assigned to any post/custom-post/page and also which are repeated

Tags: php, wordpress, post, custom-post-type, attachment

I have more than 1000 custom posts. I run a cron job to pull the posts from the third party service. When I run the job every attachment is created by deleting the old one. But there are many attachments which are of the same name and I want to delete them. The main problem is the attachments which are not linked to posts some of them are attached to a page and I don't know how to identify them. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you in advance.

The expected solution is I should have only attachments which are either assigned to post/page/custom-post and only one copy of each.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

```php
$directoryIterator = new \DirectoryIterator($directory);
while($file = $directoryIterator->next()) {

    if ($directoryIterator->isDir()) {
        continue;
    }

    $file = $directoryIterator->getFilename();

    // Check if file existst in database...

    if (!$exists) {
        unlink($directoryIterator->getFilename());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what platform you are using, so I cannot tell how to check the database part.

Comment: I am using MySQL. The problem is WordPress doesn't tell if the attachment is assigned to page or no. So that's the tricky part.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the media.
1) Open media from the left menu.
2) Switch to list view.
3) See 3rd column (Uploaded to). "Unattached" means images/pdf's which are not assigned to any post/custom-post/page.
4) Select all and delete "Unattached" files.

Comment: No. this does not work. The attachment is assigned to page and the data is stored in the serialize manner. If the answer was so simple I wouldn't have posted it here.